# Rider+Unity not respecting Roslyn code analyzer ruleset

Tags: unity-game-engine, roslyn, rider, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a Unity 2020.2.1f1 project using Rider 2019.1.3 for the IDE. I installed the Microsoft.Unity.Analyzers (1.10.0) for it by basically following the tutorial published by Unity (https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html)

I created a Default.ruleset file as prescribed by the tutorial and specified the severity of each rule, as shown below

```
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="10.0">
    <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Unity.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Unity.Analyzers">
        <!-- Full list of rule description available here https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft.Unity.Analyzers/blob/706b0a0afdc1cdd965a90cb1f2474d62d4f400b5/doc/index.md -->
        <Rule Id="UNT0001" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0002" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0003" Action="Warning" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0004" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0005" Action="None" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0006" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0007" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0008" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0009" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0010" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0011" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0012" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0013" Action="None" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0014" Action="None" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0015" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0016" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0017" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0018" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0019" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0020" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0021" Action="None" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0022" Action="Error" />
        <Rule Id="UNT0023" Action="Error" />
    </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

However, the Unity console still prints analyzer output for UNT0013:

`Assets/Scripts/Tools/UI/AspectLayoutElement.cs(63,5): info UNT0013: SerializeField attribute is invalid or redundant for property or field: 'baseHeight'.`

To make sure that the Default.ruleset rules were being used, I tried changing the severity for several other rules, intentionally writing code that violates the rules, and reimporting the Assets/Scripts/ folder and indeed the Unity console does change the output for the analyzer between `Error` and `Info` severity. However, it doesn't seem to respect the `None` or `Hidden` severity at all. It will just log to Unity console as `Info` on those settings.

I then tried switching my IDE from Rider to Visual Studio for Mac (8.9.6).

When I run Unity against Visual Studio instead of Rider, it seems to respect the rules without issue, and UNT0013 is suppressed from the logs when the severity is set to `None`.

Is there a way to fix the ruleset behavior for Unity running against Rider?

Comment: I'm also interested in this.

Comment: Have you reported the issue to either JetBrains or Unity? Please link a bug-report link here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are being reported to the Unity editor console, then this is an issue with the Unity editor build process. Neither Rider nor Visual Studio for Mac will write to the Unity editor console.